# javascript in html been using in android

Tags: javascript, android, html

I have this url for the school timetable search, but all the result and the search page are using the same url, and the main body is running by the javascript in side the html.

the url is http://epoly.tp.edu.sg/tpapp/isistt/TTServlet

so how can I get the search result in android?
the javascript from the source code  is

```
function change(dropdownvalue)
{

    document.form1.txtAction.value='ChangeSearch';
    submitForm('form1', 'TTServlet');   
}

function getTT (action, staffid)
{
    document.form1.txtAction.value=action;
    document.form1.txtSelStaffID.value=staffid;
    submitForm('form1', 'TTServlet');
}

function search (action)
{
    if (validate())
    {
        document.form1.txtAction.value=action;
        submitForm('form1', 'TTServlet');
    }
}

function validate()
{
    if (trim(document.form1.txtStaffID.value)== '' && trim(document.form1.txtStaffName.value)== '')
    {
        document.form1.txtStaffID.focus();
        alert("Please enter a search value for either Employee ID. or Staff       Name.");
        return(false);
    }
    return (true);
}

function clearFields()
{ 
    document.form1.txtStaffID.value='';
    document.form1.txtStaffName.value='';
}
```

Comment: please format your code next time, this was almost impossible to read.

Comment: sorry, I thought I had edited the question, but end up I didnt save it.

Answer (score 0):

Use `addJavaScriptInterface` to have a binding between JavaScript and Android

From Android,

```
WebView webView;
webView.loadUrl("http://epoly.tp.edu.sg/tpapp/isistt/TTServlet");

// Add JS libraries
webView.addJavascriptInterface(new TTSearch(), "TimeTable");

private class TTSearch{ 
public void SearchResult(String result) // This function is called from JavaScript
{
 Log.v(LOGTAG, "Search Result is - " + result); 
}
}
```

From Javascript,

```
var a = result;  //your result which you intend to send to android
TimeTable.SearchResult(a);
```